# ACF Date and Time Picker doesn't work in ACF repeater field

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datetimepicker, advanced-custom-fields

I was trying the WordPress Advanced Custom Fields add-on Date and Time Picker Field (https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-field-date-time-picker/), but it doesn't seem to work inside an ACF repeater field. Any ideas about how to make this add-on work? I'm not sure if it's actively maintained. It's also on GitHub at https://github.com/soderlind/acf-field-date-time-picker.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Find timepicker.js inside the plugin folder (js folder) and replace the following:

```
$el.find('input.ps_timepicker').each(function(){
    var input = $(this)
```

with

```
    acf.get_fields({ type : 'date_time_picker'}, $el).each(function(){

        var input = $(this).find( 'input.ps_timepicker' )
```

lines 31 and 32 at the time I'm checking.